# extract multiple values from a single cell in a dataframe column using pandas

Tags: python, pandas

I have a column in my dataframe as follows:

```
var1 year 
a   [2025]
b   [2025,2030]
c   [2023,2025,2030,2040]
d     .
e     .
f     .
```

I want to extract each year in each cell and make it to be as follows:

```
var1 year
a   2025
b   2025
b   2030
c   2023
c   2025
c   2030
c   2040
     .
     .
     .
```

Any ideas how can I extract them as above?

I tried the code below but could not seperated the values in the list.

```
names = ['sentence-carbon', 'sentence-water']
idx = pd.MultiIndex.from_tuples(df[names].values.tolist(), names=names)
pd.DataFrame(df['SentenceTargetYear'].tolist(), idx).stack().reset_index(names, 
name='SentenceTargetYear')
```

Answer (score 0):

You have to [`explode`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.explode.html) your dataframe if `year` column contains list:

```
>>> df.explode('year')
  var1  year
0    a  2025
1    b  2025
1    b  2030
2    c  2023
2    c  2025
2    c  2030
2    c  2040
```

If your column contains string representation of a list, you have to `eval` first:

```
>>> df.assign(year=pd.eval(df['year'])).explode('year')
  var1  year
0    a  2025
1    b  2025
1    b  2030
2    c  2023
2    c  2025
2    c  2030
2    c  2040
```

Comment: I'm getting this error when I try your second solution since year column contains string representation of a list:

        703     if kind == 'U':
    704         raise ValueError('NumExpr 2 does not support Unicode as a dtype.')
--> 705     raise ValueError("unknown type %s" % a.dtype.name)
    706 
    707 

ValueError: unknown type object